# Admob: Load request again when first request failed?

Tags: request, admob, adbannerview

Does it make sense to send another request by calling loadRequest if the first one failed? Maybe inside didFailToReceiveAdWithError? Or does the Admob code handle this itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it's not a good option.

You failed to receive an ad either because there is a problem with your config, in which case sending another request will still fail. Or the ad server is down (very unlikely) which will also result in another failure. Or there are no ads available at this time in this area for your app, in which case asking again does not help.

Just use the regular time out mechanism to check for ads at intervals.

Comment: What happens when the network is down? Does the AdMob framework try to load an ad again?

Comment: No it won't try to load an ad when there is no net connectivity. It will start loading again when connection is resumed. Which makes sense.

Comment: In my testing it does not load an ad when the connection is back online. At least in the latest SDK version 6.7.0.